# Java GAE: Process terminated because the backend took too long to shutdown

Tags: java, google-app-engine

i'm running a long Task (about 6 hours) in a Backend Instance in my Google Appengine Application.

Here is the backend configuration:

```
<backend name="backend_1">
    <class>B4_1G</class>
    <options>
        <public>true</public>
        <dynamic>false</dynamic>
    </options>
</backend>
```

When the process is running (in default thread or parallel thread, i tried both) after a random amount i time i get

```
2013-09-13 18:52:14.677
Process terminated because the backend took too long to shutdown.
```

I've looked around to find a solution, i read about the [shutdown Hook for Backend instance](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/#Java_Shutdown), which i implemented, but it seems not to be working.

```
LifecycleManager.getInstance().setShutdownHook(new ShutdownHook()
{
    public void shutdown()
    {
        log().info("Shutting down...");
        LifecycleManager.getInstance().interruptAllRequests();
    }
});
```

The log message is never shown, only the `Process terminated because...` message

I also implemented the isShuttingDown check

```
LifecycleManager.getInstance().isShuttingDown();
```

In every cycle of my process, the first thing i check is if the backend is shutting down, but this flag is never true.

The process is always "brutally" interrupted without any hook to control the shutdown (Maybe i can stop the operation saving some data for future resuming)

I thought about an "out of memory" error, but i'm not storing any "big" object in memory. Also, at every cycle, the instance variables are set to NULL, forcing the release of the memory.

Also, i'm expecting an error like this

```
Uncaught exception from servlet java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

if this is the problem

Am i the only one experiencing this kind of problem?

Already read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739411/gae-process-terminated-because-the-backend-took-too-long-to-shut-down-in-backen), but no solutions

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue with python. In my case, all I see is the terminated message. cpu, memory usage n all are fine when checked. never the less profiled and brought the memory consumption down. Still seeing the same thing. In your case it says memory issue, you could try to profile your code and lower the memory footprint. Again as I noticed in around 50 runs of the backend, shutdown handler is not guaranteed to be called. Google developers make this clear in the Google IO video on backends.

After chasing this error for sometime now, it seems AppEngine development paradigm revolves around url handlers with limitations on time, memory etc. This is applicable to long running tasks too. I redid my long term task to be executed small tasks. Task queues triggered smaller tasks which inturn run, before finish queue the next task. Never failed even once!

The advantage is that taskqueues have better failsafe/handover than just a huge cron job. One task failing does not mean the rest of the huge task list fail.

Also shutdown hook work perfectly when approaching backends with queues. Fired everytime compared to sometimes on cron jobs.